# Create and save large size image in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

Android support recommends scaled bitmap when OOM error occurs.

Are there any tools in order to be able to create a picture large size (example: 3000x3000px) and then save it to sdcards without changing its size?

Comment: Read this... http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I've read it before. It describes how to optimize images for use in the UI (for example ImageView). But I just need an existing image (stored on sdcard) add some fragments (such as shapes and text, etc.) and then save to sdcard. The new target image should match the size of the original image.

Comment: Just how were you planning to add some fragments...? May be then I can suggest something.

Comment: To add new fragments to the image I use class Canvas (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)